# Find a suitable zero equation to solve the optimization problem $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^N} f(x)$

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

Suppose we have an optimization problem for this general form of $f: \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^N} f(x)$$

and this problem is solvable. How could I construct a suitable zero equation to solve the optimization problem?

I think if $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then we can construct the zero equation as $f'(x) = 0$. With the zero equation in hand then the solution can be found with iterations of Newton's method. However I am not sure how to proceed when $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: What is a "zero equation" and how can you claim that the equation $f'(x)=0$ leads to a solution via some method? There is no method to solve a general optimization problem such as you give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is differentiable, the minimiser will satisfy the equation $\nabla f = 0$, where $\nabla f  = (f'_{x_1}, \cdots, f'_{x_n})$. Newton's method is also quite similar: if you want to numerically solve an equation $g(x) = 0$, where $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$, you take an initial approximation $x^{(0)}$ and proceed using the iteration
$$
x^{(k+1)}= x^{(k)} - [J_g(x^{(k)})]^{-1} g(x^{(k)}),
$$

where $J_g$ is the Jacobian matrix of $g$. Please note that the convergence of Newton's method is by no means guaranteed, and even if it converges it can converge to a local minimum (which may not be the global minimiser), a local/global maximum or a saddle point.